# Methodology on associating human traits to occupational tasks

Tags: regression, elastic-net

Note: See Edit 1, 2  for alternative source of human competence instead of by proxy via a Holland survey.

I am exploring research where I have a large number of occupational tasks, that is, things you do in a job, like `programming`, `research`, `lifting boxes`, etc. There are over 20,000 tasks. There are about 1000 occupations.

Each occupation has a set of core tasks, typically 20 or so.

Each occupation also has a set of personality test results, [Holland Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holland_Codes), which aggregates Holland personality survey results per occupation, that is each occupation has a set of Holland Code measurements.

I would like to associate a defensible weighting of creative, social competencies to each task. Manually labeling each task would be somewhat arbitrary and hard to defend.

My thought was to:

- Treat each task as an independent variable, with a row per occupation (This makes for a quite a sparse matrix). Each occupation only has a few tasks.
- Treat the Holland personality code results, per occupation, as dependent variables, particularly the social, artistic results
- Apply an appropriate type of regression that can handle high dimensional, co linearity and interactions such as *Elastic Net*
- Take the regression coefficients per independent variable as a measure of associated creative, social intelligence, that is repeatable and defensible for each task.

Are there criticisms to this approach that I should anticipate?

What are some better ways to associate the level of human competencies, such social, creative competencies, required for given tasks?

**edit 0** - normalized language to use competencies instead of different terms (intelligence vs aptitudes)

**edit 1** - The use of Holland codes has been rightly criticized as they are preferences, not competencies. So far in the industrial/organization pysch literature I haven't come across much on using Holland codes as a proxy for anything else, nor as an indirect measure of occupational competency.

However I did see that ONET gives [occupation requirements](https://www.onetcenter.org/content.html#cm_4.A) in Generalized Work Activities (GWA) which describe frequency of various aggregated tasks grouped by general statements.

But using GWAs raises a similar question: these activities were not designed to measure social, creative competence. At that point is the only resort to have several human raters re-interpret them in terms of social, creative, etc dimensions?

**edit 2** - I found a MIT paper, ["Racing with and against the Machine"](http://k12accountability.org/resources/For-Parents/Racing_With_and_Against_the_Machine_-Changes_in_Occupational_Skill.pdf) by MacCrory, et al, wherein they select variables from both [ONET's Worker Characteristics and Occupational Requirements](http://www.onetcenter.org/content.html) which conflates preferences for requirements since they analyze effects on occupations using work preferences. But, what I find interesting is that they use PCA and evaluate the orthogonal dimensions empirically (see Data and Methods). Their methods of constructing orthogonal dimensions is interesting here.

In my case I would then select from Occupation Requirements only (measuring requirements, competencies) and pull out those in which human competences (creativity, artistic) of interest largely act out within. I figure if this method is good enough for MIT then it's good enough for me. I'll place a bounty on this question and see if anyone provides a better approach.

Comment: It looks like the Holland Occupational Themes might not quite fit your purposes in two ways: they concern habits or preferences rather than competence (which is what I presume what you mean by "intelligence"), and they posit social and creative personalities as separate constructs instead of just one.

Comment: Kodiologist makes some good points. While the use of Holland Codes is well established in the I/O Psych literature, to get a better baseline the first thing I would do is scan the *Journal of Applied Psychology* for recent papers that have the Codes as a topic as well as any recent research leveraging the O*Net. At that point, the question becomes one of how best to structure the data matrix to produce a model since having 20,000 independent variables with ~1,100 rows may not work. This scan might uncover suggestions as to more "tried and true" I/O methodologies to addressing your question.

Comment: Updated answer for clarity, would like analyze competence.

@DJohnson - Will look more into I/O literature; there may be work on assigning competencies from preference measures under Holland Codes, not sure.

Comment: Kodiologist - Great points, re: separate constructs, I envisioned a multivariate regression or otherwise regress on each construct separately.

Comment: One way to think about this problem is as a massive contingency table between occupations and tasks. Given that, bayesian tensor regression might be a useful strategy for modeling. David Dunson at Duke is one of the key architects of this method. Here are links to a couple of papers. Guhaniyogi, Qamar and Dunson *Bayesian Tensor Regression*. Also, Lin *Tensor Product Space ANOVA Models*. I've found ungated copies of both.

Comment: Another possible approach is faceted classification. The Wiki article on this method describes it as "is a classification scheme used in organizing knowledge into a systematic order. A faceted classification uses semantic categories, either general or subject-specific, that are combined to create the full classification entry. Many library classification systems use a combination of a fixed, enumerative taxonomy of concepts with subordinate facets that further refine the topic." It sees wide use in occupational classification... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faceted_classification